# No route matches missing required keys: [object_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have several nested routes in my application. I'm building a database to categories startups by what industry they are in and their various competitors within that industry.

I've been searching for the answer to this error but am having trouble figuring it out:

**Edit** Added full error message and categories_controller.rb

Error message:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Categories#show

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories", :id=>"5", :industry_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:industry_id]
```

[image: error I'm getting when hitting edit in the index view]

Nested routes:
     resources :industries , only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update] do
        resources :categories do
          resources :startups, module: :categories
        end 
      end

```
Category.rb

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :startups, as: :startupable
    belongs_to :industry
    belongs_to :user
end


Industry.rb

class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :categories
end

startup.rb

class Startup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :startupable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

c

```
ategories_controller.rb

class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @categories = Category.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
    authorize @categories
  end

  def show
  end


  def new
    @industry = Industry.find(params[:industry_id])
    @category = @industry.categories.new
    flash[:notice] = "Category created."
    authorize @category
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @industry = Industry.find(params[:industry_id])
    @category = current_user.categories.build(category_params)
    respond_with @industry
    authorize @category
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to @industry
    flash[:notice] = "You have succesfully deleted the category."
  end

  private
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
      authorize @category
    end
    def correct_user
      @category = current_user.categories.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to categories_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this Category" if @category.nil?
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

For some reason, I'm not calling the Industry_id when hitting the **view** button or my categories aren't associating properly with their industry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question with the `categories_controller.rb` Also please post the full error message instead attaching a screen-shot. It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show.html.erb

**UPDATE**

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_industry_category_path(@category.industry, @category) %>
```

Comment: That worked, now I'm getting a new error but I think I can work this one out, I'll mark this correct. thanks! P.S. the new error is from the startupable routes... undefined method `category_startups_path I'm guessing I need to reconfigure this some how.